# How to automated curved mouse movements in Python (with pyautogui or any other similarmodule)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate mouse movements in a way that would look *somewhat* human-like. The reason why I need to do this is because I'm currently working on promotional videos for a web-app and I want to show how it's used. I don't want to just record my own movements because what I mean by "somewhat" human-like is that I want it to feel kind of organic, but I still want it to be perfect.

I've been using pyautogui and time for now and it works great. I can get the cursor to move at whatever speed I want. I can make it slow down with tweening functions. It looks almost human, but it's all in straight lines. I'd like to have the cursor move in curves.

Is that possible? Either that means using pyautogui with another module or simply other modules completely, that'd be fine. Also, I've found only one question here about this subject and I'm not sure the poster had the same objective as I do. They were talking about a bezier curve. I'm not particularly familiar with those so ideally, if it's possible of course, I'd like a simpler solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: The question is better than many, but has problems.  (1) Where is the code you're trying to replace?  (2) Just what do you mean by "organic ... but ... perfect"?  This is a UX feeling, not a specification for an archive of programming solutions.  (3) Why won't you learn about Bezier curves, and what curves *are* you comfortable using?  (4) What happened when you drew with some of your comfortable curves?

Comment: (1) I'm not trying to replace current code. I'm writing new code. I've used pyautogui for other videos, but I've only used straight lines, such as go from point A to point B.

(2) I just mean that while I want the mouse movements to be perfect, which is why I want to use python rather than just screen record myself moving my mouse, I want it to look organic, meaning it should not be so robotic that it just moves in straight lines.

(3) I could, but I wanted to know if there was a faster solution.

(4) I haven't used curved movements yet. That's the point of my question.

Comment: Movement in most modules is point-to-point via straight lines: curves are drawn as a series of very short straight lines.  Thus, any curve you draw will be similarly slow ... as far as I've seen package implementations.  Perhaps there's some optimization for a "draw_circle" or similar function in some package, but I haven't seen it in my limit-channel usage.

Comment: I've had nice-looking results with a section of an ellipse, no more than 1/4 of the total circumference.  Shallow circular arcs are also good, if you don't want to bother with the ellipse scaling.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll look into modules for drawing circles.

Comment: I would also look into the algorithm for generating the xy coordinates of Bezier curves. They're fairly straightforward to calculate, and then you can use those xy coordinates for pyautogui.moveTo()